# How to filter all observations for the last measurement year prior a cut-off year and all of the observations for all years past the cut-off year

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter all observations for the **last measurement year prior a cut-off year** and all of the observations for all years past the cut-off year.

Here's an example:

```
d <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                cut_off = c(2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016),
                year = c(2000,2010,2010,2015,2015,2017,2017,2020,2024,2001,2009,2016,2017,2017,2021,2023),
                value = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160))

> d
   group cut_off year value
1      1    2017 2000    10
2      1    2017 2010    20
3      1    2017 2010    30
4      1    2017 2015    40
5      1    2017 2015    50
6      1    2017 2017    60
7      1    2017 2017    70
8      1    2017 2020    80
9      1    2017 2024    90
10     1    2016 2001   100
11     2    2016 2009   110
12     2    2016 2016   120
13     2    2016 2017   130
14     2    2016 2017   140
15     2    2016 2021   150
16     2    2016 2023   160
```

And here's my desired output:

```
desired <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
            cut_off = c(2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016),
            year = c(2015,2015,2017,2017,2020,2024,2009,2016,2017,2017,2021,2023),
            value = c(40,50,60,70,80,90,110,120,130,140,150,160))

> desired
   group cut_off year value
1      1    2017 2015    40
2      1    2017 2015    50
3      1    2017 2017    60
4      1    2017 2017    70
5      1    2017 2020    80
6      1    2017 2024    90
7      2    2016 2009   110
8      2    2016 2016   120
9      2    2016 2017   130
10     2    2016 2017   140
11     2    2016 2021   150
12     2    2016 2023   160
```

Selecting all the years past (and including the cut-off) is easy:

```
require(dplyr)
d %>%
+   filter(year >= cut_off)
  group cut_off year value
1     1    2017 2017    60
2     1    2017 2017    70
3     1    2017 2020    80
4     1    2017 2024    90
5     2    2016 2016   120
6     2    2016 2017   130
7     2    2016 2017   140
8     2    2016 2021   150
9     2    2016 2023   160
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the last year preceeding the cut-off year. I tried combinations using `lag()` as well as with and without `group_by()` but cannot get it to work, e.g. (but doen't work)

```
d %>%
  filter(year >= cut_off | lag(year) < cut_off)
```

Comment: Is row 10 a typo? Should `cut_off` be 2017 or `group` 2?

Comment: @LMc yes that what indeed a typo (good catch!) and your simplified version works perfectly when making `group = 2` in row `10`. However, thinking about it now, cut-off year may change within the groups and for that your initial approach works great.  @jpsmith 's answer is also very slick as it works without the extra `mutate` step. I accepeted your answer though since you answered first and provided two solutions depending on the structure of the dataset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are taking the most recent year *before* `cut_off`, there is no need for two filtering expressions. Once you find the most recent year before you want all rows greater than or equal to that value (which will always include  `cut_off`):

```r
library(dplyr)

d |> 
  mutate(diff = cut_off - year) |>
  filter(year >= year[which.min(diff[diff > 0])], .by = group) |> 
  select(-diff)
```

If row 10 is a typo (see my comment) then you could simply do (assumes your data are already sorted by group/year):

```r
d |> 
  filter(year >= year[match(unique(cut_off), year) -1], .by = group)
```

Comment: I just wanted to add this here since I have been extensively testing your solution. It turns out that I also have cases within groups where all years are larger than the cut_off. This will trigger an error message. One way to fix this was to have another filter step prior to your filter, i.e. `filter(!all(diff < 0), .by = group)`. This will exclude those groups.

Comment: I hope it's ok to ask here again. What if I want to be flexible with the number of dates prior the cut_off? I wrote this filter here based on your code: `filter(year >= unique(year[diff == unique(sort(diff[diff > 0]))[2]]), .by = group)`. There I can indicate for example `2` for two year prior the cut_off. Do you think this filter is reasonable? I tested it and it seems fine. If you a better way of doing this would you mind adding this to your answer? Thx!

Comment: Actually this one is more concise: `filter(year >= sort(unique(year[diff > 0]), decreasing = TRUE)[2], .by = group)`

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some example data.

Comment: You might consider grouping by `group` and `cut_off`. The problem you are bound to run into with your solution stems from the way `>=` and all relational operators work: if one vector is shorter than the other then *recycling* occurs. For example `c(2013, 2012) > c(2010, 2012)` does an element wise comparison. However, `c(2013, 2012, 2011) > c(2010, 2012)` recycles the values of the shorter vector. Effectively it is testing `2013 > 2010`, `2012 > 2012`, and then starts recycling so the last logical value returned is `2011 > 2010`.

Comment: Recycling can be very handy in some situations but in your case I would guess that it is more likely to cause issues. As mentioned, it would be better for you to post more representative data in a new question.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate you got back to me! Ok I will think this through and post another question.

Answer (score 5):

```r
d <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                cut_off = c(2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016),
                year = c(2000,2010,2010,2015,2015,2017,2017,2020,2024,2001,2009,2016,2017,2017,2021,2023),
                value = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160))
  
library(tidyverse)

d |> 
  mutate(year_prior_to_cutoff = year[year < cut_off] |> sort() |> last(), .by = group) |> 
  filter(year >= cut_off | year == year_prior_to_cutoff)
#>    group cut_off year value year_prior_to_cutoff
#> 1      1    2017 2015    40                 2015
#> 2      1    2017 2015    50                 2015
#> 3      1    2017 2017    60                 2015
#> 4      1    2017 2017    70                 2015
#> 5      1    2017 2020    80                 2015
#> 6      1    2017 2024    90                 2015
#> 7      2    2016 2009   110                 2009
#> 8      2    2016 2016   120                 2009
#> 9      2    2016 2017   130                 2009
#> 10     2    2016 2017   140                 2009
#> 11     2    2016 2021   150                 2009
#> 12     2    2016 2023   160                 2009
```

Answer (score 5):

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  mutate(helper = max(year[year < cut_off]), .by=group) %>%
  filter(year >= cut_off | year == helper) %>%
  select(-helper) %>% 
  arrange(group, year)
```

```
   group cut_off year value
1      1    2017 2015    40
2      1    2017 2015    50
3      1    2017 2017    60
4      1    2017 2017    70
5      1    2017 2020    80
6      1    2017 2024    90
7      2    2016 2009   110
8      2    2016 2016   120
9      2    2016 2017   130
10     2    2016 2017   140
11     2    2016 2021   150
12     2    2016 2023   160
```

Answer (score 4):

A single step solution could be to use `which()` in the filter statement:

```
library(dplyr) 

d %>%
  filter(year[which(year == cut_off) - 1][1] <= year,
         .by = group)

   group cut_off year value
1      1    2017 2015    40
2      1    2017 2015    50
3      1    2017 2017    60
4      1    2017 2017    70
5      1    2017 2020    80
6      1    2017 2024    90
7      2    2016 2009   110
8      2    2016 2016   120
9      2    2016 2017   130
10     2    2016 2017   140
11     2    2016 2021   150
12     2    2016 2023   160
```